# Can a 4K HDMI cable transmit a 5120x1440 signal?

Tags: hdmi, 4k-resolution

"4K" is usually used as a name for resolutions like 3840x2160 and 4096x2160.

Now the question is: 
When I buy a "4K"-HDMI-Cable, will it work with a resolution of 5120x1440, which has a lower number of pixels in total but more than 5K pixels in width?

Comment: No such monitor exists to my knowledge. Are you planning a setup of multiple
monitors adding up to a resolution 5120x1440?

Comment: 4K is not a valid HDMI specification version. A cable can be compliant to HDMI v2.0 2.0a or 2.0b for 4K. Even an HDMI 1.4b can transmit 4k signals (with reduced refresh rate).

Comment: @Robert: The poster is probably just quoting some marketing hype. The real question is whether his video card is capable of 5120x1440.

Comment: I got an UltraWide 49" display (DELL U4919DW) with this resolution. When connecting it via USB-C it has this resolution, so the video card can do it. I want to connect it via an AV receiver that only supports HDMI.
@Robert so even HDMI 1.4b would transmit a 5120x1440 signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an adapter from USB-C to HDMI supporting 4K and it works. But it only supports 4K at 30Hz, which is not much because you see everything in a choppy movement. So I gonna upgrade this to a 4K@60Hz one.

**So the answer is yes.**

Answer (score 0):

I have a 5120x1440 super ultra wide the AGON 49".
I also looked on various forums regarding the samsung G9, and the LG 49".
It seems that HDMI 2.0 and even 2.1, users are all having issues getting 5120 x 1440 to work over HDMI. It doesn't appear to be a pixel issue alone, the length of the monitor does matter. So even though our monitors are technically lower pixels, but the 5120 just won't run over HDMI.

The work around for some people seem to use the Picture by picture mode, which some monitors have. Then they use two HDMI's. So it's basically dual monitor setup with no bezel. Might be okay for productivity, but not sure about gaming.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).